# Parse.com, how to save Multiple Checkboxes values using javascript

Tags: checkbox, save, parse-platform

Using Javascript @ cloud code in parse.
i managed to extract the values of multiple check boxes from the req.body.

however, i have to loop them and set then save the values to the parse class as below (below code is from my main.js file)

```
var checkBoxes = req.body.country;
for (var counter=0; counter < checkBoxes.length; counter++) {
 country.id = checkBoxes[counter];                      
 coffer.set("countryPointer", country);
 coffer.set("offerPointer", offer);
 coffer.save();
}
```

P.S
The country.id changes, the offer.id is a fixed value.

**Problem: Only the first checkbox value is saved.**

Comment: Are you wanting multiple `coffer` objects, or multiple `countryPointer` in the one `coffer`?

Comment: There is a many to many relation between country and offer. that's why the table coffer is created to save pointers for such relations.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `for` loop, you need to create a new `coffer` for each entry.

Currently you are just updating and re-saving the same entry multiple times, so only the last save works.

Note that you don't **have** to create a join table like in SQL, you can just add an array/relation (depending on size) to either/both your Country/Offer table. There are some use cases where a join table is better, but just be aware that it is not the only solution on Parse.

You can read more about creating one-to-many and many-to-many relationships in the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-pointers).